# tag h1 disappears in fullscreen mode

Tags: android, html, tags

I've got a small issue: on Android device by fullscreen mode tag h1 disappears from web page
but tag h2 doesn't disappears

why is this happening?

p.s h1 tag placed inside header tag and inside article tag

Comment: Can you share part of your h1 tag code or more?

Comment: `<article>  
<h1>my title</h1>  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>  
</article>  `

Comment: Please at first read this topic **[Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)**